# How to test if a parameter has been set to the empty string?

Tags: bash, variable

I want to test if a parameter is an empty string `""`.

When the parameter is not set, the test should fail.

1. Why does the following not succeed?

   ```
   $ unset aa
   $ if [ ${aa}=="" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
   yes
   ```
2. What shall I do instead?

Comment: Did you use the word “parameter” in relation to [your recent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/420061/117549)?

Comment: Is the lack of whitespace around the `==` a typo?

Comment: @don_crissti, `${aa?}`? that would throw an error if `aa` was unset?

Comment: @ilkkachu could you elaborate why  whitespace should be around `==`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes.

Comment: Since we learned from the recent question that there are some differences between variables and parameters, you might be clearer in this question what your goal is.

Comment: So I use "parameter" @JeffSchaller

Comment: @don_crissti, yeah, though exiting with an error is a bit different than just failing the test, that's why I asked... :)

Comment: @don_crissti The `${var?}` test will yield an error of "./script: line 7: var: parameter null or not set", so, no, it will stop the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test`, i.e. `[`,  needs whitespace around the operators, basically because otherwise `foo==` would be taken as containing an operator, even though it's a valid string. The `[[ .. ]]` construct works the same in this. (See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32210/170373) and [BashFAQ 031](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for the `[` vs `[[` difference.)

So, `[ ${aa}=="" ]` will *always* be true, since `[ string ]` is the same as `[ -n string ]`, i.e. it tests that the string is not empty. And here the string contains at least `==`.

Then `[ ${aa} == "" ]` will be an error if `aa` is unset or empty, since an empty variable expanded without quotes disappears and `[ == foo ]` isn't a valid test. If `aa` has a nonempty value, it's false. (`[[ ${aa} == "" ]]` would work even without the quotes, since `[[ .. ]]` is special.)

Of course `[ "${aa}" == "" ]` would test that `aa` is either unset or empty, the same as `[ -z "${aa}" ]`.

---

To test that it's both set, and empty, we could use `[ "${aa+x}" ] && [ -z "$aa" ]`, or a nifty combination of those, stolen from an [answer by @Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147362/170373):

```
if [ "${aa+x$aa}" = "x" ] ; then
    echo "aa is empty but set"
fi
```

(that works since if `aa` is unset, the `+` expansion expands to the empty string, and if it's set, it expands to `x$aa`, which is just `x` if `aa` is empty.)

```
$ foo() { [ "${1+x$1}" = "x" ] && echo "set but empty" || echo "unset or non-empty"; }    
$ foo; foo ""; foo bar
unset or non-empty
set but empty
unset or non-empty
```

Comment: Thanks. Is "[[ ${aa} == "" ]] would work even without the quotes, since [[ .. ]] is special" mentioned in bash manual?

Comment: @Tim, yeah, it's special in that it's not a regular command like `[`, but part of the shell syntax. The manual at least mentions that word splitting doesn't happen in it, and it's listed along with other shell constructs, like `if`, and `(( .. ))` ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b)),  
See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32227/170373

Comment: To be pedantic, you could say that `test` i.e. `[` requires that operators and strings must be *separate arguments,* and that *in the shell* this is accomplished by putting whitespace around the operators.  Since strictly speaking `test` never sees the whitespace itself (the shell strips it), and if anyone is perverse enough to invoke `test` from C code with an `execve` call, they won't need whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

Your (attempted) test `$aa == ""` is equivalent of comparing two empty strings with each other, which results in a true result. This is because the shell will expand unset variables to the empty string. Without the spaces around the `==`, the test will always be true as it's the same as testing on the two character  string `==`. This string is always true.

Instead, in `bash`:

```
$ unset aa
$ if [ -v aa ]; then echo Set; else echo Not set; fi
Not set
$ aa=""
$ if [ -v aa ]; then echo Set; else echo Not set; fi
Set
```

The full test for an empty string would therefore be

```
if [ -v aa ] && [ -z "$aa" ]; then
    echo Set but empty
fi
```

From `help test` in `bash`:

> `-v VAR`         True if the shell variable `VAR` is set.

Or, from the `bash` manual's "CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS" section:

> `-v varname`
>
> True if the shell variable `varname` is set (has been assigned a
>                 value).

With the `-v` test, you test on the variable's *name* rather than on its value.

---

If you really want to do a string comparisson, you *could* do something like

```
if [[ "${aa-InvalidValue}" != "InvalidValue" ]] && [ -z "$aa" ]; then
    echo Set but empty
fi
```

The expansion `${variable-value}` will expand to `value` if `variable` is unset.

Note that the very similar `${variable:-value}` will expand to `value` if `variable` is unset *or null* (the empty string).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why string comparison via `==` not work?

Comment: @Tim I just added some text about that.

Comment: This will only work for shells that have -v option (not sh, not POSIX).

Comment: @isaac It's tagged with `bash`.

Comment: That it is tagged with bash does not prevent other possible answers that are still valid in bash. In any case, what I said is a fact, not a complaint.

Answer (score 3):

First, And I assume you do know, the `==` require spaces around it. The use of `==` is valid only in bash, ksh and zsh, better use `=`. Also, the variables expanded inside a test should be quoted. So, I'll assume that the line is actually:

```
unset aa ; if [ "${aa}" = "" ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
```

With that, your questions:

#### Why does the following not succeed?

Because the expansion of a plain unset var is identical to the expansion of a plain variable set to null (from what test '[' could do).

```
I mean, "$aa" is the same value for both an unset aa or a null aa.
```

To show how that works, try this script (note that the script is sh, it works the same in dash, bash, ksh and/or zsh):

```
#!/bin/sh

blanktest(){
    if [ "${aa}" = "" ]; then echo "$1 yes"; else echo "$1 no"; fi
}

unset aa; blanktest unset
unset aa; aa="";  blanktest blank
unset aa; aa="e"; blanktest value
```

Which, on execution will yield:

```
$ ./script
unset yes
blank yes
value no
```

#### What shall I do instead?

Use a parameter expansion called "Use Alternative Value." :

```
${aa+x}
```

which will yield an x if the variable is set (either null or value) and a null if the variable is unset.

Use this test instead:

```
[ "x${aa}x" = "x${aa+x}" ] && echo yes || echo no
```

Testing script (again, sh compatible):

```
#!/bin/sh

blanktest(){
    if [ "x${aa}x" = "x${aa+x}" ]; then echo "$1 yes"; else echo "$1 no"; fi
}

unset aa; blanktest unset
unset aa; aa="";  blanktest blank
unset aa; aa="e"; blanktest value
```

On execution, will print this:

```
$ ./script
unset no
blank yes
value no
```

There are several possible variations, if you are interested.